# Need to understand this Kotlin code in buildSrc Gradle project

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I'm a newbie in Kotlin and I'm currently learning how to integrate Gradle with Kotlin. Looking up in the internet I saw this code.

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Project

import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*

/**
 * Configures the current project as a Kotlin project by adding the Kotlin `stdlib` as a dependency.
 */
fun Project.kotlinProject() {
    dependencies {
        "compile"(kotlin("stdlib"))
    }
}
```

This is saved as buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Dependencies.kt. Because Kotlin has so many syntactic sugars I have a bit of a trouble understanding that piece of code. The `"compile"()` part, that is an `invoke()` convention? Can anyone provide an explanation for this code and the Gradle buildSrc, as to why the code looks like that?

Here is the buildSrc/build.gradle.kts file

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Here is another build.gradle.kts in the root directory

````kotlin
plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72" apply false
}

allprojects {

    group = "com.example.test"

    version = "1.0"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Make the root project archives configuration depend on every sub-project
//    subprojects.forEach {
//        archives(it)
//    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start with reading https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html.

In particular, it links to the [Kotlin DSL API docs](https://gradle.github.io/kotlin-dsl-docs/api/) and says `org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*` and `org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.plugins.dsl.*` are automatically imported (so that `import` line can probably be removed). Looking at them, we can indeed find `invoke` operators. This one is inside `dependencies { ... }`, so we can look at [`DependencyHandlerScope`](https://gradle.github.io/kotlin-dsl-docs/api/org.gradle.kotlin.dsl/-dependency-handler-scope/index.html):

```
operator fun String.invoke(dependencyNotation: Any): Dependency?
operator fun String.invoke(dependencyNotation: String, dependencyConfiguration: ExternalModuleDependency.() -> Unit): ExternalModuleDependency
operator fun String.invoke(group: String, name: String, version: String? = null, configuration: String? = null, classifier: String? = null, ext: String? = null): ExternalModuleDependency
operator fun String.invoke(group: String, name: String, version: String? = null, configuration: String? = null, classifier: String? = null, ext: String? = null, dependencyConfiguration: ExternalModuleDependency.() -> Unit): ExternalModuleDependency
operator fun <T : ModuleDependency> String.invoke(dependency: T, dependencyConfiguration: T.() -> Unit): T
operator fun Configuration.invoke(dependencyNotation: Any): Dependency?
operator fun Configuration.invoke(dependencyNotation: String, dependencyConfiguration: ExternalModuleDependency.() -> Unit): ExternalModuleDependency
operator fun Configuration.invoke(group: String, name: String, version: String? = null, configuration: String? = null, classifier: String? = null, ext: String? = null): ExternalModuleDependency
operator fun Configuration.invoke(group: String, name: String, version: String? = null, configuration: String? = null, classifier: String? = null, ext: String? = null, dependencyConfiguration: ExternalModuleDependency.() -> Unit): ExternalModuleDependency
operator fun <T : ModuleDependency> Configuration.invoke(dependency: T, dependencyConfiguration: T.() -> Unit): T
operator fun invoke(configuration: DependencyHandlerScope.() -> Unit): Unit
```

and the first one is clearly applicable.

Unfortunately, there is an [index](https://gradle.github.io/kotlin-dsl-docs/api/alltypes/index.html) but it lists only types and not functions, there doesn't seem to be a way to see e.g. all `invoke` methods in Kotlin DSL :(

Looking at the code in IDEA (or Android Studio) should show you the types involved, which will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yep they are actually operator invoke. When you do `()` on a string kotlin calls the `operator fun String.invoke()` defined in that context.

Example are better than words:

```kotlin
// top level context
operator fun String.invoke(a: String, b: Int, c: () -> Unit) {
    println(this)
    println(a)
    println(b)
    c()
}

// call it like this
"test"("parameter a", 27) { println("parameter c") }

// Results:
// test
// parameter a
// 27
// parameter c
```

And here is the the code which does the same but inside a receiver, i.e. instead of top-level function it calls the invoke function defined inside of the class. [Play with the code yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/lch3p3ffk)

[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke) are more examples from kotlin docs